# JS while loop change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JS code that can track positions of DOM elements by use of their class. However, I need this class name changed for a specific amount of times. My code so far is this:

All the code that says added, is my poor try to make it work, just to give you an idea of what I am meaning.

```
     var offset = 0,
        xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0,
        item_number = 0; //added code

$(document).ready(function(){


    while(item_numer<5) { //added code
        $(".item" + item_number ).draggable({ //added code, the "item" has to be shown on the website as "item0".

        containment: '#house_wall1',

        drag: function(){
            offset = $(this).position();
            xPos = offset.left;
            yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        },

        // Find original position of dragged image.
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // Show start dragged position of image.
            var Startpos = $(this).position();
            $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
        },

        // Find position where image is dropped.
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // Show dropped position.
            var Stoppos = $(this).position();
            $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
        }
    });
    item_number++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your while loop has a typo: `while (item_numer<5)`.  `item_numer` is always undefined, which I believe always evaluates to <5.

Comment: Yeah I did that now thanks, but it's more about the syntax that I don't understand. like how is this possible in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're placing the ending `}` a bit too soon.

The call to `.draggable()` and the `Object` literal passed to it actually stretch quite a few lines down to the 1st `});` near the bottom. The loop should surround all of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    while (item_number < 5) {
        $('.item' + item_number).draggable({
            // around 20 lines
        });

        item_number++; // increment counter
    }                  // and end of loop
});
```

Though, the counter may not be necessary. Since you're using a `class` selector, `class` names can be reused and `.draggable()` will apply to each of the matched elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item').draggable({
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: How about the code now? :) I have tried doing what you said

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply missing an increment on `item_number`?

```
while(item_numer<5) {
  $(".item" + item_number ).draggable({ /* stuff */ });
  item_number++;
}
```

Comment: I added that but it still does not work, is the syntax correct for my code? thanks

Comment: No, it's not. You're not correctly closing the object literal or function call on the second line of my code snippet above.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you had item_number++ at the very bottom... that's def not the right spot. Syntax errors aside, you'll need to increment _in the while loop_ otherwise you'll never escape it.